# recursive xml-parsing function not working as intended

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml, recursion, xml-parsing

I'm trying to parse an XML document and use the data to build a (simpler) json object of this form:

```
{id: '1', name: 'content-types', children: [{id: '2', name: 'requirements': children: [... and so on ...]]}
```

My XML has nodes that look like the following (I've only included one -- they can be arbitrarily nested):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head/>
  <body class="taxonomies">
    <div class="taxonomy">
      <span class="id">3484069771</span>
      <span class="name">Content Types</span>
      <span class="locale">en</span>
      <div class="concepts">
        <div class="concept">
          <span class="id">3484058507</span>
          <span class="name">Promotional Publications</span>
          <div class="concepts">
            <div class="concept">
              <span class="id">3551765771</span>
              <span class="name">Datasheets</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I use the following code to build a JSON tree from the XML:

```
buildConceptTree: function(xml){
    const doc = new dom().parseFromString(xml)
    var tree = []
    var selector = "//*[@class='taxonomies']"
    var count = 0  // this should keep track of the depth of the node being used
    function recurse(s, odd){
        var nodes
        console.log(count)
        console.log(s)
        var arr = []

        nodes = xpath.select(s, doc)
        nodes.forEach(node => {
            try {
                var children = node.childNodes
                var keys = Object.keys(children).filter(x => {return Number(x)})
                keys.forEach(key => {
                    var child = children[key]
                    console.log('child is: ')
                    console.log(child)
                    var obj = {}
                    var grandchildren = child.childNodes
                    var grandkeys = Object.keys(grandchildren).filter(x => {return Number(x)})

                    grandkeys.forEach(gk => {
                        var gc = grandchildren[gk]
                        try {
                            var nodevalue = gc['attributes'][0]['nodeValue']
                            switch(nodevalue){
                            case 'id':
                                obj['id'] = gc['textContent']
                            case 'name':
                                obj['name'] = gc['textContent']
                            case 'concepts':
                                count++
                                var rx = /taxonomy/
                                    if(!rx.test(s)){
                                        s = s+"/*[@class='taxonomy']"
                                    }
                                else{
                                    s = s
                                }
                                if (!odd){
                                    s += "/*[@class='concepts']"
                                }
                                else {
                                    s += "/*[@class='concept']"
                                }
                                odd = !odd
                                obj['children'] = recurse(s, odd)
                            }
                        }
                        catch(e){
                        }
                    })
                    arr.push(obj)
                })
            }
            catch(e){
            }

        })
        return arr


    }

    var tree = recurse(selector, false)
    return tree

},
```

As it stands, this function produces something like the JSON form I mentioned, but with many missing nodes.

Also, it seems that my recursive function is not terminating in a simplest case as it recurs along deeper branches of the xml tree.  I get the following logged in the console (for example), but there are no nodes that are 191 degrees deep:

```
    191
     parser.js?d3c4:83 //*[@class='taxonomies']/*[@class='taxonomy']/*[@class='concepts']/*[@class='concept']/*[@class='concepts']/*[@class='concept']/*[@class='concepts']/*[@class='concept']/*[@class='concepts']/*[@class='concept']/*[@class='concepts']/*[@class='concept']/*[@class='concepts']/*[@class='concept']/*[@class='concepts']/*[@class='concept']/*[@class='concepts']/*[@class='concept']/*[@class='concepts']/*[@class='concept']/*[@class='concepts']/*[@class='concept']/*[@class='concepts']/*[@class='concept']/*[@class='concepts']/*[@class='concept']/*[@class='concepts']/*[@class='concept']/*[@class='concepts']/*[@class='concept']/*[@class='concepts']
     parser.js?d3c4:92 child is:
```

Can anyone help me figure out how to change this function to make it get the data I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might've missed some requirements, but the the issue seems less complicated once you stop looping over all elements and start querying the exact elements you expect:

```js
// Parse the xml string to a document
const parser = new DOMParser();
const xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(
  getXML(),
  "text/xml"
);

// The main logic to go from an xml element to an object
const parseTaxonomy = (taxonomy, id = 1) => ({
  id,
  name: taxonomy.querySelector(".name")
    .innerText
    .toLowerCase()
    .replace(/\s/g, "-"),
  children: Array.from(
    (taxonomy.querySelector(".concepts") || { children: [] })
      .children
  ).map(t => parseTaxonomy(t, ++id)) // Note the ++
});

// Run on the first taxonomy
// If the top level contains multiple elements, use .map
console.log(
  parseTaxonomy(
    xmlDoc.querySelector(".taxonomy")
  )
);

// The data
function getXML() {
  return `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head/>
  <body class="taxonomies">
    <div class="taxonomy">
      <span class="id">3484069771</span>
      <span class="name">Content Types</span>
      <span class="locale">en</span>
      <div class="concepts">
        <div class="concept">
          <span class="id">3484058507</span>
          <span class="name">Promotional Publications</span>
          <div class="concepts">
            <div class="concept">
              <span class="id">3551765771</span>
              <span class="name">Datasheets</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>`;
};
```

Note: I changed the part in which you put the comment because the comment wasn't closed and I expected it to have another wrapper around the child taxonomies.

Comment: Thanks, I like your approach.  Unfortunately this doesn't work with the data as I provided it, since the data is nested in '.concepts' and '.concept' divs, not always '.taxonomy'.

Comment: Can you provide a larger data sample then? Or you could try to change those selectors to match your data (i.e. change `".taxonomies" to ".concepts")

Comment: I realized I accidentally put a '.taxonomy' element next to the comment in the original xml, which probably confused you.  I edited it to make it clear.  The xml in my question now has several levels of nesting and should be enough.

Comment: Just to be clear, '.taxonomy' only appears at the next-to-top level; all nesting is inside of '.concepts' and '.concept'.  One idea that occurs to me is to use your object builder to toggle between '.concepts' and '.concept' to replace '.taxonomy' each time it recurses.

Comment: I've changed the child-selector to look for `.concepts`' children and it seems to produce the required results